# How to save such content in a txt file

Tags: python, arrays, list, save, text-files

My content looks as follows:

```
[[array([175, 178, 182, ..., 172, 167, 164], dtype=uint8)
  array(['b'], dtype='<U1')]
 [array([126, 125, 126, ..., 152, 143, 137], dtype=uint8)
  array(['b'], dtype='<U1')]]
```

When I try to save the above content (say `X`) as follows:

```
np.savetxt('x.txt', X.reshape(np.shape(X)), fmt='%f')
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%f %f')
```

I know that changing `fmt='%s'` might solve this issue, but the other issue is that I will be calling another function that doesn't work with strings.

Any ideas on how I can save `X` to the file without having the above error?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**

The above format has been obtained since I did the following:

```
images.append([np.array(image_array_to_vector),np.array([label])])

X = np.array([[i[0],i[1]] for i in images])
```

Comment: How did you even get your data into this bizarre format in the first place?

Comment: You seem to have a two-dimensional array of object dtype, whose elements are more arrays, including several copies of `array(['b'], dtype='<U1')`. This makes no sense, especially with how you were trying to save your array.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Please see my **EDIT** above about how this data was obtained

Comment: I'm trying to combine the image vector and the relative label. Makes sense?

Comment: It'd make more sense to have separate arrays for images and labels, or encode the labels as integers so you can have a homogeneous array.

Comment: Yes, I have it that way. What I'm trying to do is embed the "label" in the image vector. I had the label as an integer, but changed it to a character to distinguish the label. But, let's say that I would like to combine an integer label with the image vector and save that to a text file, what should I do in this case?

Comment: With an integer label, you'd make it an extra column in a 2-dimensional array where most of the columns represent image vector data and the last column is the label. You could then use `savetxt` as normal, probably `np.savetxt('x.txt', X, fmt='%d')`.

Comment: If you really want character labels and integer image data in the same data structure, it might be better to use a structured dtype.